# Absence of topology in semi-dirac materials

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-insulators, topological-order, topological-phase

Good morning everybody, I am facing a problem when calculating the topological invariant in a semi-dirac system, whose Hamiltonian is:
$$
 H=k_x^2\sigma_x+k_y\sigma_y
$$
My question is that this Hamiltonian has time-reversal symmetry, of the form $H(k)=H(-k)^*$ and therefore should not have topological invariant. Instead I have calculated the edge states and they exist. Does anyone know why it has edge states, but in theory it does not have topological invariance. Is it because the model is developed to too low order? Can anyone think of a way to prove the topology?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It may be a topological crystalline insultator?

Comment: It's too quick to conclude there are no topological invariants for the model just because of time-reversal symmetry. After all, topological insulators are also time-reversal-invariant. Does the edge states still exist if a mass term $m\sigma_z$ is added? This mass preserves the time-reversal symmetry you mentioned.

Comment: @MengCheng Yes they exist i have calculated them. The only thing I don't understand is that according to the classification that depends on symmetries, if you have T=+1 you should not have invariant for dim=2 ?

Comment: I have recently check that it also has quiral symmetry and particle-hole symmetry, and maybe mirror symmetry?